# Unsolved Incomplete use of invalid type for node

Tags: c++

I'm working on an assignment for school, and I'm getting a repeating error that I can't seem to get rid of. The following errors repeat continually throughout my code

```
hw_9_1.cpp: In member function ‘void DLinkedList::addNode(Node*)’:
hw_9_1.cpp:32:31: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct DLinkedList::addNode(Node*)::node’
     temp = new(struct node);
                           ^
hw_9_1.cpp:32:27: note: forward declaration of ‘struct DLinkedList::addNode(Node*)::node’
     temp = new(struct node);
                       ^~~~
hw_9_1.cpp:33:15: error: request for member ‘xy’ in ‘* temp’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
     temp->xy = node->xy;
           ^~
hw_9_1.cpp:33:24: error: expected primary-expression before ‘->’ token
     temp->xy = node->xy;
                    ^~
hw_9_1.cpp:34:15: error: request for member ‘next’ in ‘* temp’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
     temp->next = NULL;
```

I have been told that this is often due to a missing include file, but I have checked multiple times to make sure all necessary files are included. Can anyone give me another idea about what is causing these errors?

My Code for the assignment that is relevant to this issue is as follows

```
#include "std_lib_facilities_4.h"
#include "Simple_window.h"
#include "Graph.h"



struct Node {
Point xy;
Node* next;
Node* prev;
}*start;
class DLinkedList {
public:
Node* head;
Node* tail;  
DLinkedList() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {}
void addNode(Node*); // add a Node to the list
Node* removeNode(Point); //remove a Node from the list
};
void DLinkedList::addNode(Node* node) {




if (start == NULL)
{
    head=start;
    struct node *s, *temp;
    temp = new(struct node); 
    temp->xy = node->xy;
    temp->prev=NULL;
    temp->next = NULL;



}

struct node *tmp, *q;
int i;

head=start;
temp = new(struct node);
tmp->xy = node->xy;


q->next=tail
if (q->next == NULL)
{
    q->next = tmp;
    tmp->next = NULL;
    tmp->prev = q;
    tail->next=temp;
}





}


Node* DLinkedList::removeNode(Point XY) {

    struct node *tmp, *q;
     /*first element deletion*/
    if (start->xy == XY)
    {
        tmp = start;
        start = start->next;  
        start->prev = NULL;

        free(tmp);

        return;
    }
    q = start;
    while (q->next->next != NULL)
    {   
        /*Element deleted in between*/
        if (q->next->xy == XY)  
        {
            tmp = q->next;
            q->next = tmp->next;
            tmp->next->prev = q;

            free(tmp);

            return;
        }
        q = q->next;
    }
     /*last element deleted*/
    if (q->next->xy == XY)    
    {   
        tmp = q->next;
        free(tmp);
        q->next = NULL;


        return;
    }



}



struct DLL : Shape { // Doubly Linked List
void add(Point p) { Shape::add(p); }
void set_point(int i,Point p) { Shape::set_point(i,p); }
void draw_lines() const;
Point last_removed_point;
DLinkedList this_list;
private:

};
```

Comment: What's `struct node`, and how, if at all, is it related to `struct Node`?

Comment: You seem to mix `c` and `c++` syntax. Try `Node` instead of `struct node`

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error message is that you don't have any type named `struct node`. So you can't `new` a `struct node`.

To me it seems that the main problem is that you mix `C` and `C++` syntax. In `C` the correct syntax would be to repeat the `struct` part of the type but in `C++` `struct` is not repeated.

So the fix is simply to replace

```
struct node
```

with

```
Node
```

all places in the file.

Besides that you have a number of places where you mix up `tmp` with `temp`

Also you have a problem in

```
Node* DLinkedList::removeNode(Point XY)
```

as you say the function will return a `Node*` but inside the function, you call `return` with no arguments.

You probably want

```
void DLinkedList::removeNode(Point XY)
```